# Can not create directory on hdfs of hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I can not operate my hdfs about permission. I executed hadoop fs -ls /  and return
drwx------   - ubuntu supergroup          0 2015-09-02 09:58 /tmp
user of OS is user1,

How to change the user of hdfs to user1? I add dfs.permissions.enabled to false in hdfs-site.xml, and format hdfs again, but the problem still exists.
could anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

There in no affair of `OS user`, namely `user1`.

You communicate with `hadoop server` via a `hadoop client`.

So you should check you `hadoop client`'s conf, on my machine `hadoop-site.xml`.

In `hadoop-site.sml`, you set the corresponding username and password to your hdfs

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.job.ugi</name>
  <value>yourusername,yourpassword</value>
  <description>username, password used by client</description>  
</property>
```

Comment: thank you. which version is your hadoop?  i can not find this property in documents.